# Facebook App Stream_publish

Tags: facebook, stream, publish

I'm trying to make my facebook application autopost to a wall after they have accepted the permissions, ived tryied alot of things but i just cant get it working.

This is one of the things ived tryid:

```
    FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'feed',
        to: friendId,
        name: 'title',
        link: 'http://host.com/title_link.com',
        picture: 'http://host.com/image.jpg',
        description: 'description',
        caption: 'caption',
     },
     function(response) {
        // Check for a posting to wall
        if (response && response.post_id) {
            // do some logging
        }
     }
   });
```

Is there anyone that got a sample code :)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, your example is not working because there is one comma too much after

```
 caption: 'caption'
```

.